# Random { } in Python Tkinter Text Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

In Python, I used Tkinter and made a text widget for the bot to display a random date. But for some reason the text widget displayed random { } in the text. I can't figure out what is causing all the { } to appear.
[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnD5D.png)

The part of the code that does this is here:

```
self.text_widget = Text(self.ui, width=20, height=2, bg="#f1f1f1", fg="#656565",
                            font=Font1, padx=5, pady=5)
self.text_widget.place(relheight=0.845, relwidth=1, rely=0.08)
self.text_widget.configure(cursor="arrow", state=DISABLED)

# Create Random Date
year = random.randrange(2021, 2121)
    monthd = random.randrange(1, 12)
    if monthd == 1:
        month = "January"
    if monthd == 2:
        month = "Febuary"
    if monthd == 3:
        month = "March"
    if monthd == 4:
        month = "April"
    if monthd == 5:
        month = "May"
    if monthd == 6:
        month = "June"
    if monthd == 7:
        month = "July"
    if monthd == 8:
        month = "August"
    if monthd == 9:
        month = "September"
    if monthd == 10:
        month = "October"
    if monthd == 11:
        month = "November"
    if monthd == 12:
        month = "December"
    date = random.randrange(1, 29)
    answer = ""
    answer = "on " , date , ", " , month , year
    
    

    # Display Date
    msg2 = "Bot:   " , answer ,  "\n\n\n"
    self.text_widget.configure(state=NORMAL)
    self.text_widget.insert(END, msg2)
    self.text_widget.configure(state=DISABLED)
    print("[OK] Self Message Displayed\n")

    self.text_widget.see(END)
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of the {} ?

Comment: Have you tried using `randint`?

Comment: Looks like each element of the tuples is being wrapped in `{` `}` when converting them to strings. If you don't want the braces, you'll need to format the strings yourself.

Comment: @CoderTang, Yes, I did, still the same result.

Comment: @Brian I replaced it with: 
msg2 = "Bot:   {d1} {d2}, {d3} \n\n\n".format(d1 = date, d2 = month, d3 = year)
seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: @Terry-065 You could also use an [f-string literal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (e.g. `msg2 = f"Bot: {date} {month}, {year} \n\n\n"` or, even better, proper [datetime formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format the string yourself. Python is adding the {} when converting it to a string.

Try replacing `answer` with:

```
answer = f"{date} {month}, {year}"
```

And then replacing `msg2` with:

```
msg2 = f"PyPhet: {answer} \n\n\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be

```
msg2 = "Bot:   " , answer ,  "\n\n\n"
```

because it creates a tuple.

Just change it to

```
msg2 = "Bot:   " + answer +  "\n\n\n"
```

Also I notice another problem

```
monthd = random.randrange(1, 12)
```

will only return 1 to 11.

`answer` has the same problem as `msg2` and therefore the same solution.

Comment: msg2 = "Bot:   " + answer +  "\n\n\n" creates an error :
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

Comment: For the: monthd = random.randrange(1, 12). Thanks for the correction, I already fixed that.

Comment: @Terry-065 change `answer` to `answer = "on " + str(date) + ", " + month + str(year)`. `answer` is a tuple in your current code so it will cause the same error

Comment: @bdbd Another error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: Ok updated that. Cast the ints to string or use f-strings `answer = f"on {date}, {month} {year}"`